# Qt SQLite Unable to Open Database after many successful inserts/updates on Mac

Tags: macos, qt, sqlite

I'm trying to use SQLite with Qt 5.3 and access a central DB from 3 separate threads. Each thread has its own connection to the DB as per many suggestions I've seen here. Inserts are happening on a file scanner thread and updates are happening on another. It works perfectly fine on Windows and on Mac when running a debug build. But when I have a release (build for profiling) build it fails with the errors seen below. At least on my machine, it *always* fails after insert 272.. though I can push that out a few by adding in some delays after each insert.

```
Success: insert into MediaItems (Type, UUID, Path, Width, Height, Parents) values (:Type, :UUID, :Path, :Width, :Height, :Parents)
1 rows affected
New ROWID: 270

Success: insert into MediaItems (Type, UUID, Path, Width, Height, Parents) values (:Type, :UUID, :Path, :Width, :Height, :Parents)
1 rows affected
New ROWID: 271

Success: insert into MediaItems (Type, UUID, Path, Width, Height, Parents) values (:Type, :UUID, :Path, :Width, :Height, :Parents)
1 rows affected
New ROWID: 272

DB Error on thread: Scanner for /Users/adamh/PicTest
Error: insert into MediaItems (Type, UUID, Path, Width, Height, Parents) values (:Type, :UUID, :Path, :Width, :Height, :Parents)
unable to open database file
Unable to fetch row

DB Error on thread: DB_MAIN
Error: update MediaItems set UUID = :UUID, Path = :Path, Children = :Children, Parents = :Parents where ROWID = 194
unable to open database file
Unable to fetch row
```

Example of my insert/update code:

```
execQueryWrapper(QSqlQuery q)
{
   bool result = false;

   if (!q.exec())
   {
      AS_LOG(q.lastQuery() + QS("\n"));
      QSqlError err = q.lastError();
      AS_LOG(err.databaseText() + QS("\n"));
      AS_LOG(err.driverText() + QS("\n"));
   }
   else
   {
      AS_LOG(q.lastQuery() + QS("\n"));
      AS_LOG(QS("%1 rows affected\n").arg(q.numRowsAffected()));
      result = true;
   }

   return result;
}

insertQuery(QString table, QStringList cols, QVariantList vals, uint * rowID)
{
   AS_ASSERT(cols.count() == vals.count());

   QSqlQuery q = getQuery();

   QString statement = QS("insert into %1 (%2) values (%3)").arg(table).arg(cols.join(QS(", "))).arg(QS(":") + cols.join(QS(", :")));
   q.prepare(statement);

   for (int i = 0; i < cols.count(); i++)
   {
      q.bindValue(QS(":") + cols[i], vals[i]);
   }

   bool result = execQueryWrapper(q);
   if (result)
   {
      *rowID = q.lastInsertId().toInt();
   }

   return result;
}

updateQuery(QString table, QStringList cols, QVariantList vals, QString conditionCol, QVariant conditionVal)
{
   AS_ASSERT(cols.count() == vals.count());

   QSqlQuery q = getQuery();

   QStringList combined;
   foreach(QString col, cols)
   {
      combined.append(col + QS(" = :") + col);
   }

   QString statement = QS("update %1 set %2 where %3 = %4").arg(table).arg(combined.join(QS(", "))).arg(conditionCol).arg(conditionVal.toString());
   q.prepare(statement);

   for (int i = 0; i < cols.count(); i++)
   {
      q.bindValue(QS(":") + cols[i], vals[i]);
   }

   return execQueryWrapper(q);
}
```

For the most part, this works... it just eventually fails. I thought at first it was a thread concurrency thing but as far as I know I'm doing everything I can do prevent that. I know I could batch the inserts but for a variety of reasons that's not really possible at the moment... I need single atomic transactions for each new item mainly because the insert requests are coming in as the scanner finds things.

The actual DB is a file in the user directory on all systems. Again, this ONLY happens on Mac in release builds.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you access the database in the sqlite shell after it errors?

Comment: Yup... works just fine. All the data is there, right up to 272